# Hosted Blazor WASM on HTTPS

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, blazor-webassembly, iis-8

Can somebody help me why my hosted Blazor WASM app does not accept SSL certificate on our IIS server, please?
I tried it with a self-signed and corporate certificates, too, but browsers do not accept them. 443 port is enabled and binded. They say it is not secure. The app is deployed in InProcess mode.

Comment: I think you should include any and all errors returned by the browsers when you say they are not accepted. You might also have very high corporate rules and GPO that prevents something necessary.

Comment: The browser can decide the connection isn't secure for a variety of reasons, so merely saying you tried two kind of certificates indicates that you have others unchecked. Run a report and common issues will be clear, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html

Comment: Self-signed certificates are inherently not trusted by your browser. You need to import the root certificate into the trust store for the browser. Once the browser knows you trust this root certificate, all certificates signed by this will show up as trusted. Is there any error message return?

Answer (score 0):

Corporate certificate was not good to use in the intranet because its top level domain is different.
Self-signed certificate is working now but it is among the Personal certs. CN is equal the site domain and the cert name (it is important), too.